# How to retrieve Redis values into a array in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I want to get all values from my redis and store it into a array in nodejs

Here is my present code,

```
redisClient.keys("Serial*", function (err, keys) {
    keys.forEach(function (key, i) {
        redisClient.hgetall(key, function (err, currencyData) {
            console.log(currencyData);
        })
    });
});
```

it allows me to output all values to console 
but I need to use these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need a the currencyData in an array -

```
function getAllCurrency(callback){
    redisClient.keys("Serial*", function (err, keys) {
        var allCurrencyData = [];
        var counter = keys.length;
        keys.forEach(function (key, i) {
            redisClient.hgetall(key, function (err, currencyData) {
                if(err)
                    return callback(err);
                console.log(currencyData);
                allCurrencyData.push(currencyData);
                counter--;
                if(counter == 0)
                   callback(null, allCurrencyData);
            })
        });
    });
}
```

Calling from another function -

```
getAllCurrency(function(err, allCurrency){
    // use allCurrency array here
});
```

This is not the best code. Also the order of elements in the array might not be the same as the keys array. For a better asynchronous control try using the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library or Promises.

Comment: `allCurrencyData` cannot be modified from inside another function.
here `hgetall` is a function 
`allCurrencyData` will be a seperate variable when used inside `hgetall`